# How to create object attribute with name from input id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<input id="some_id" value="some_value">
```

I need to create `{some_id: some_value}` (in other words i need to use as name of the attribute value of id) from upper input.

I tried:

```
jQuery('[name="page-numbers[]"]').map(function () {
  return { jQuery(this).attr('id'): jQuery(this).val()};
}).get();
jQuery('[name="page-numbers[]"]').map(function () {
  return {this.id: this.value};
}).get();
```

But every time i get an error near `{this.id:`. If only call `this.id` or `this.value` or same jQuery - result returns.

Comment: what is exactly you want to return? I'm having the feeling you want a map of id values to input values ( {"name" : "Bong", "use" : "puffing"} ) and instead what you are getting is an array of maps ( [{"name" : "Bong", "use" : "puffing"] ) . Is this really what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you should use [square bracket notation](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/square_brackets.html) for defined empty object:

```
$('[name="page-numbers[]"]').map(function() {
    var obj = {};
    obj[this.id] = this.value;
    return obj;
}).get();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create some sort of "input_id" : "input_value" key-value assoc, you are doing it with the wrong method, I'd say. Try this:

```
var assocs = {};
jQuery('[name="page-numbers[]"]').each(function () {
  assocs[this.id] = this.value;
})
```

using .map you will get an array of many one key/value maps as a result.

Comment: yes, you right. May be you can correct my code page_numbering: function(){
    var assocs = {};
    jQuery('[name="page-numbers[]"]').each(function(){
       assocs[this.id] = this.value;
    });
    console.log(assocs);
    return assocs;
   }

Comment: What it is exactly not doing? And can you present me a jsfiddle example, so we can test it with a live example?